# Need advice on whether to fork puppet module torrancew-account

Tags: github, module, puppet, user-accounts

I'm running puppet enterprise I need a feature that's in the devel branch of module [torrancew-account](http://github.com/torrancew/puppet-account).

Specifically I need the feature that allows me to puppetize system user accounts that share home directories. It's called "allowdupes."

I don't know how to fork modules nor am I sure if I can just git clone the devel branch of torrancew-account into /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/modules and expect it to work. I can't wait for the author to pull in his allowdupes feature.

Answer (score 2):

You can pull the repository off of github and switch to the branch.

```
 $ git clone https://github.com/user/repo
 $ cd repo
 $ git checkout branch_name
```

After that `branch_name` will be your current working branch. If you wanted to you can fork the repo on git hub. Clone it to your workstation, merge it to master, then push back to github. From there you can use your fork rather then the original authors.

https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo

```
 $ git clone https://github.com/yourname/repo
 $ cd repo
 $ git merge branch_name
 $ git push origin master
```